# Извлечение данных localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Есть форма, данные которой записываются в массив `contacts`, потом функция `updateTable` берет данные из массива и заполняет/рисует таблицу. 
Необходимо переделать и добавить `localStorage`, чтобы функция `upadateTable` брала данные с `localStorage`.

```js
var contacts = [];
var Contact = function(name, surname, phone) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.phone = phone;
}
var addContact = function() {
  var nameValue = document.querySelector('#name').value
  var surnameValue = document.querySelector('#surname').value
  var phoneValue = document.querySelector('#phone').value
  var contact = new Contact(nameValue, surnameValue, phoneValue);
  validate();
  if (nameValue && surnameValue && phoneValue) {
    contacts.push(contact);
    localStorage.setItem('tab', JSON.stringify(contacts));
    updateTable();
  }
}
var updateTable = function() {
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#contacts-table tbody');
  while (tbody.firstChild) {
    tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    const {
      name,
      surname,
      phone
    } = contacts[i];
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = `<td>${i+1}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${surname}</td><td>${phone}</td>`;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
var validate = function(customerId) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.hasAttribute("rule-required")) {
      element.classList.add('invalid');
      if (!element.value && !document.getElementById("req" + i)) {
        var mass = document.createElement('div');
        mass.setAttribute("id", "req" + i);
        mass.classList.add('ivalid');
        mass.innerHTML = 'Заполните поле';
        console.log(mass);
        element.parentNode.appendChild(mass);
      } else if (element.value && document.getElementById('req' + i)) {
        resetMass = document.getElementById('req' + i);
        resetMass.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onload = updateTable;
```

```css
#customerId {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#contacts-table {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ivalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">




<form name="customer" id="customerId">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='name'>Ваше имя</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="customerName" placeholder="введите имя" rule-required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='lastname'>Ваша Фамилия </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="surname" type="text" placeholder=" введите фамилию" rule-required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='number'>Номер телефона</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="number" placeholder="введите номер" rule-required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="addContact(this.form)" class="btn btn-default" id="btn">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table" id='contacts-table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Телефон</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tbody'>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: в чем проблема то? какая ошибка?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как переписать функцию updateTable, чтобы она заполняла таблицу беря данные из localStorage, сейчас она берет их из массива.

Comment: _«Проблема в том, что я не знаю как переписать функцию»_ - вероятно, Вы ошиблись сайтом... напомню, что stackoverflow не является сервисом удовлетворения хотелок (типа "мне вот это нужно, ну-ка делайте!"). Попробуйте решить задачу самостоятельно, и если в процессе этого возникнут вопросы - сформулируйте их четко и подробно, а также приложив код своего решения или [mcve]. На качественные вопросы, сообщество с готовностью дает столь же качественные ответы.